# Cannot use/import npm packages in Meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, import, npm-install, simple-schema

I am not able to do:

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
```

or to import any other npm package with this command. I have already installed the package via `meteor npm install --save simpl-schema`.

I have also tried to import other npm dependencies like:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Therefore, I think that I generally missed something important to be able to require NPM packages in my client-side code or that I am using a wrong structure?

I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

in the browser console.

### Edit

I have called `meteor npm install` before running the app.

If I code this line `import moment from 'moment';` on a server side js-file, I get the following error:

> app\server\startup\profilemanagement.js:1
>   (function(NPM,Assets){(function(){import moment from 'moment';
>
> **SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**  at C:...meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:392:18 at
>   Array.forEach () at Function.*.each.*.forEach
>   (C:...meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0:1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11) at C:...meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:220:5 at
>   C:...meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:463:5 at
>   Function.run
>   (C:...meteor\local\build\programs\server\profile.js:510:12) at
>   C:...meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:462:11

I am not sure if I installed the babel packages correctly. I think something went wrong there. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "abbrev": "^1.1.0",
    "addressparser": "^1.0.1",
    "ajv": "^5.2.2",
    "ansi-regex": "^3.0.0",
    "aproba": "^1.2.0",
    "are-we-there-yet": "^1.1.4",
    "asn1": "^0.2.3",
    "assert-plus": "^1.0.0",
    "asynckit": "^0.4.0",
    "aws-sign2": "^0.7.0",
    "aws4": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "balanced-match": "^1.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "bcrypt-pbkdf": "^1.0.1",
    "block-stream": "0.0.9",
    "boom": "^5.2.0",
    "brace-expansion": "^1.1.8",
    "buildmail": "^4.0.1",
    "caseless": "^0.12.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
    "chartjs-color": "^2.2.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.9.0",
    "co": "^4.6.0",
    "code-point-at": "^1.1.0",
    "color-convert": "^1.9.0",
    "color-name": "^1.1.3",
    "combined-stream": "^1.0.5",
    "concat-map": "0.0.1",
    "console-control-strings": "^1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "cryptiles": "^3.1.2",
    "dashdash": "^1.14.1",
    "debug": "^3.0.1",
    "deep-extend": "^0.5.0",
    "delayed-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "delegates": "^1.0.0",
    "ecc-jsbn": "^0.1.1",
    "extend": "^3.0.1",
    "extsprintf": "^1.3.0",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^1.0.0",
    "fontawesome": "^4.7.2",
    "forever-agent": "^0.6.1",
    "form-data": "^2.3.1",
    "fs.realpath": "^1.0.0",
    "fstream": "^1.0.11",
    "fstream-ignore": "^1.0.5",
    "gauge": "^2.7.4",
    "getpass": "^0.1.7",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",
    "har-schema": "^2.0.0",
    "har-validator": "^5.0.3",
    "has-unicode": "^2.0.1",
    "hawk": "^6.0.2",
    "hoek": "^4.2.0",
    "http-signature": "^1.2.0",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.19",
    "inflight": "^1.0.6",
    "inherits": "^2.0.3",
    "ini": "^1.3.4",
    "is-fullwidth-code-point": "^2.0.0",
    "is-typedarray": "^1.0.0",
    "isarray": "^2.0.2",
    "isstream": "^0.1.2",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jodid25519": "^1.0.2",
    "jsbn": "^1.1.0",
    "json-schema": "^0.2.3",
    "json-schema-traverse": "^0.3.1",
    "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.1",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "jsonify": "0.0.0",
    "jsprim": "^1.4.1",
    "libbase64": "^0.2.0",
    "libmime": "^3.1.0",
    "libqp": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mailcomposer": "^4.0.2",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.11",
    "mime-db": "^1.30.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.17",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ms": "^2.0.0",
    "nan": "^2.7.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.6.37",
    "nodemailer": "^4.1.0",
    "nodemailer-fetch": "^2.1.0",
    "nodemailer-shared": "^2.0.0",
    "nopt": "^4.0.1",
    "npmlog": "^4.1.2",
    "number-is-nan": "^1.0.1",
    "oauth-sign": "^0.8.2",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "object-inspect": "^1.3.0",
    "object-keys": "^1.0.11",
    "once": "^1.4.0",
    "os-homedir": "^1.0.2",
    "os-tmpdir": "^1.0.2",
    "osenv": "^0.1.4",
    "path-is-absolute": "^1.0.1",
    "path-parse": "^1.0.5",
    "performance-now": "^2.1.0",
    "process-nextick-args": "^1.0.7",
    "punycode": "^2.1.0",
    "q": "^1.5.0",
    "qs": "^6.5.1",
    "rc": "^1.2.1",
    "readable-stream": "^2.3.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0",
    "request": "^2.82.0",
    "resolve": "^1.4.0",
    "resumer": "0.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.1.1",
    "semver": "^5.4.1",
    "set-blocking": "^2.0.0",
    "signal-exit": "^3.0.2",
    "sntp": "^2.0.2",
    "sshpk": "^1.13.1",
    "string-width": "^2.1.1",
    "string.prototype.trim": "^1.1.2",
    "string_decoder": "^1.0.3",
    "stringstream": "0.0.5",
    "strip-ansi": "^4.0.0",
    "strip-json-comments": "^2.0.1",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "tape": "^4.8.0",
    "tar": "^4.0.1",
    "tar-pack": "^3.4.0",
    "through": "^2.3.8",
    "tough-cookie": "^2.3.2",
    "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
    "tweetnacl": "^1.0.0",
    "uid-number": "0.0.6",
    "util-deprecate": "^1.0.2",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "verror": "^1.10.0",
    "wide-align": "^1.1.2",
    "wow.js": "^1.2.2",
    "wrappy": "^1.0.2",
    "yallist": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

### Second edit

It seems to be that (maybe since the last update?) I have a major issue with the meteor installation and its npm dependencies. I am not able to create a new meteor project due to this error:

> Error: Error: Could not install npm dependencies for test-packages:
>   Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c
>   C:\Users...\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0._1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd
>   install npm ERR! code ENOGIT npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH npm
>   ERR! npm ERR! Failed using git. npm ERR! Please check if you have git
>   installed and in your PATH.

You can check this error here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8585. It tells that me that no Npm dependencies can be installed because of not finding the Git-path.

However, the solutiuon to reinstall Git did not work for me. So, I think  something went generally wrong since the last meteor update. Maybe the only solution is to reinstall meteor completely or use an older version? I started this project from my computer with an older meteor version and uninstalling and reinstalling Babel did not make any difference.

Comment: The error seems the be related to a different place in code (syntax error), is there any information about lines, classes error stack etc?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I do not have any further information about specific lines or anything instead of the fact, that this error only occures, when I have that `import...` line in my client side code. When I click on "sources" in chrome I can see  `(function(){

import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema'; ... ` with that line highlited in red. So it tells me that this error is because of exactly that line. Is that code correct or do I maybe have to use another syntax or a path for 'simpl-schema' ?

Comment: Ok some thoughts on that 1. Have you called `meteor npm install` before running the app? 2. Does the error occur on the server side too? If so please post the error stack from the server console. 3. Are you sure the Babel packages are installed correctly? Please post your package.json

Comment: @Jankapunkt Many thanks, I made a huge edit on my post.

Comment: It does look like a babel issue: __1.__ If you try it on a different project, is it working then? __2.__ If you try to uninstall & re-install babel is it making any difference? __3.__ Is it a project you started on your computer or got it from somewhere else?

Comment: @user7386177 thanks, I answered your questions in my last edit, but I think it is a major issue of my meteor implementation.

Comment: Which version of meteor are you using now and with which one do you want to use?

Comment: I am now using 1.6.0_1. I will see which one I have to use that it works. Or maybe I just need to reinstall meteor.

Comment: If I would be you I would try to reinstall meteor using the chocolatay install, if not I think you have a better chance for professional help in the meteor forum community. Hope you work it out! and once you do please answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it! Although I don´t know exactly what produced the error, I could solve the issue by creating a new meteor project with the `--bare` flag (so now I know that all npm dependencies are installed correctly to ensure that I can use `'import'`) and copied my code into the project. However, than I got another error message which told me that my bootstrap is not compatible with my jquery version. Before solving this, I had to delete `codemirror` in my `client/vendor` folder, which produces another error

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ‘…/…/lib/codemirror’

Than I installed `jquery@2.2.4` plus all required datatable npm dependencies I use in my code to keep the compatibility of my applied bootstrap and jquery. Now I can use `import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema'` and all other imports and no more errors occure.

So lastly, some npm and/or packages were wrong and the initial error could be solved by creating a new meteor project. The other errors were related to bootstrap/jquery compatibility and codemirror.